# Drag a file from my GTK app to another app (not the other way around)

Tags: drag-and-drop, gtk

I have searched for examples, but all the examples were the opposite direction (my app is getting file drag-and-drop from another application). But this must be possible because I can drag a file from Files (Nautilus) to another app, Text Editor (gedit).

Could you show me a very simple example of a GTK Window with one widget on it, and when I drag from the widget to Text Editor, it passes a text file on the system (such as `/home/user/.profile`) to the Text Editor so that it will open the text file?

Comment: I haven't quite solved this yet. It should be simpler! However, I've created a GitHub repo if you want to look at [the code](https://github.com/SamMatzko/SODemos/blob/master/gtk_drag_and_drop_file.py) I have so far. When you drag a file from Nautilus and drop it on the "Drop" button, you can see all the data. But when you drag from the "Drag" button and drop it in gedit, nothing happens. I've also found a simple [gtk drag-and-drop demo](https://github.com/tom-hoffman/simplepygtkdragdrop), which helped me a bit. I'll let you know if anything turns up, or you could watch my repo if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. Yeah, when I tried dragging from the "Drag" button over to Text Editor, the cursor became a hand with a plus mark, but releasing the mouse button did nothing. But Nautilus itself is written in GTK, right (since it is Gnome's official file manager)? I wonder the GTK team simply don't provide an example for this. In .NET, implementing file drag-and-drop from my application is so easy requiring only two lines of code.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I looked into your code and it had `drag_button.drag_source_add_text_targets()`. I don't know GTK well (just a beginner), but that function did not look right because we are trying to drag file, not text. So, I searched the web with that function's name, and found `drag_source_add_uri_targets` right below that function in the list. I replaced the function with that, and file drag-and-drop to Text Editor worked.

Comment: @SylvesterKruin I have tried it further and it worked with other applications like VS Code or Files, etc. So, I think it is the answer.  If you post your code (with the fix) as an answer, I will mark it as the solution so that people in the future who look for the same thing could easily find your solution.

Comment: Of course, that makes perfect sense! I should have thought of that. I tried using `get_uris()` and `set_uris()`, but of course that wouldn't work without using `add_uri_targets()`. Yes, I'll post the answer as soon as I get a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make it so that your application can receive *files*, you need to use `uri`. In the function you bind to `drag-data-received`, you can use `data.get_uris()` to get a list of the files that were dropped. Make sure that you call `drag_dest_add_uri_targets()`, so that the widget can receive URIs.

This code example has one button that drags a file, and another button that can receive it. You can also drag the file and drop it into any file-receiving app, such as gedit (Text Editor) or VSCode.

```py
import gi
gi.require_version("Gdk", "3.0")
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk, Gdk

window = Gtk.Window()
window.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)

box = Gtk.HBox()
window.add(box)

# Called when the Drag button is dragged on
def on_drag_data_get(widget, drag_context, data, info, time):
    data.set_uris(["file:///home/user/test.html"])

# Called when the Drop button is dropped on
def on_drag_data_received(widget, drag_context, x, y, data, info, time):
    print("Received uris: %s" % data.get_uris())

# The button from which the file is dragged
drag_button = Gtk.Button(label="Drag")
drag_button.drag_source_set(Gdk.ModifierType.BUTTON1_MASK, [], Gdk.DragAction.LINK)
drag_button.drag_source_add_uri_targets() # This makes sure that the buttons are using URIs, not text
drag_button.connect("drag-data-get", on_drag_data_get)
box.add(drag_button)

# The button into which the file can be dropped
drop_button = Gtk.Button(label="Drop")
drop_button.drag_dest_set(Gtk.DestDefaults.ALL, [], Gdk.DragAction.LINK)
drop_button.drag_dest_add_uri_targets() # This makes sure that the buttons are using URIs, not text
drop_button.connect("drag-data-received", on_drag_data_received)
box.add(drop_button)

window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Mr Kruin's answer was for Python's GTK. The language I actually wanted was C#. Using his code as a hint, I modified the default GtkApplication project like so, and it worked on Linux.

```csharp
private MainWindow(Builder builder) : base(builder.GetRawOwnedObject("MainWindow"))
{
    builder.Autoconnect(this);

    DeleteEvent += Window_DeleteEvent;

    _button1.DragDataGet += (o, args) =>
    {
        args.SelectionData.SetUris(new string[]{fullFilePath});
    };

    Gtk.Drag.SourceSet(_button1, Gdk.ModifierType.Button1Mask,
        new TargetEntry[0],
        Gdk.DragAction.Link);

    Gtk.Drag.SourceAddUriTargets(_button1);
}
```

On Windows, however, it did not work. I have tried both `string fullFilePath = "file:///c:/windows/win.ini"` and `string fullFilePath = "c:\\windows\\win.ini"` and none of them seemed to work.